# Use a map for this object with arrays?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning about JS and TypeScript and I need to generate a separate React component for each of these items:

Say I have this object

```
var regions = {
    NA: ["US", "ABC1"],
    EU: ["GB", "LX", "IT"],
    FE: ["JP", "DEF1"],
    CN: ["CN"]
}
```

I'm trying to loop through and return a component for each key (NA/EU/FE/CN) and each item in the array (US, ABC1, etc.)

I can print out the values I want in a for loop:

```
for (let key in region) {
    for (let item in region[key]) {
        console.log("key: " + key + " item " + region[key][item]);
    }
}
```

as a sanity test, but instead of doing this, I want each item to be mapped to a Component so that from the function, I can return an entire list of Components. Any recommended ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear exactly what you are looking for when you say "return a component", but I'll give it a go with what I think you are saying. To fit into your loop code you could do something like the following:

```
const regionComponents = [];
for (let key in regions) {
    for (let item in regions[key]) {
        regionComponents.push(<MyComponent region={regions[key][item]} />);
    }
}

return regionComponents;
```

Or if you wanted to shorten it a little bit:

```
return regions.map(region => region.map(subRegion => <MyComponent region={subRegion} />));
```

(Obviously that will return a 2D array with components, but if you are simply then putting that within JSX elsewhere to render React will handle de-nesting for you).

If this isn't what you were looking for, leave a comment / edit your post to be a little clearer and I'll try my best to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally certain this is what you're trying to do, but you could use something like lodash's `mapValues` function to iterate over your object, and then turn each item of each array into a new component.

Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ll5n988mwm